# Creating subgroups network connections in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a way to complete a task.

With a table of connections network:
connection_from   connection_to

```
| connection_from | connection_to|
|:----------------|-------------:|
| A               |     B        |
| A               |     C        |
| G               |     C        |
| D               |     F        |
```

I would like to create a script to create a list of all values connected in any way to eg. A. For my table, it should create a table with values: A, B, C and G - the connection to G is not direct - it's because of connection A->C, C->G.

The connection works two ways: there is no difference between A->B and B->A.

I am working with big tables so efficiency of code is also important.

Comment: Unfortunately with your data architecture uber fast is not likely going to happen because this requires recursion. And since A->B is the same as B->A you are going to have to parse the tree twice.Checkout using a recursive cte. For you example I would assume that the output you stated you want would be because you want to search for relations for A?

Answer (score 2):

This is a graph-walking problem -- so that means recursive CTEs.  I find that the challenging is keeping the list of already visited nodes, to prevent infinite recursion.

The following handles this by stuffing the visited nodes into a string:

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('G', 'C'), ('D', 'F')) v(cfrom, cto)
     ),
     edges as (
      select cfrom, cto from t 
      union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select cto, cfrom from t 
     ),
     cte as (
      select 'A' as c, convert(varchar(max), ',A,') as cs
      union all
      select e.cto, cs + e.cto + ','
      from cte join
           edges e
           on e.cfrom = cte.c
      where cte.cs not like '%,' + e.cto + ',%'
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3087fb2faf6f05e84ae03082a0629502) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you! Still i have a problem tough. You have enlisted all the possible conections in third line. I have about 100,000 possible connections, so there is no way i could write them like you did

Comment: @ja213214215 that is because Gordon needed to use a cte to have a table of values. In your case you would use your actual table.

Comment: @SeanLange so where do I need to make these changes? Only in the begining of the code?:
from my_table v(cfrom, cto)

Comment: The entire cte named "t" in the above code is your table. Start with the edges cte.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But for my table it keeps producing the same outcome in a loop. For example for D, it keeps posting in result D,A,D,A,D,A.... in one column. And i mean the first column "c". There is no point of stopping in executing this query.

Comment: @ja213214215 . . . That shouldn't be happening.  However, there was a typo in the answer -- even though it worked in the SQL Fiddle.  Perhaps that will fix your query as well.

Comment: I fixed it, there was a problem my my dataset. The query works great to find every path, but my goal is to create a list of all possible values connected to A - eg. i don't need to know if X is connected to Z through Y or other value, but the information that it is connected is enough for me. It's all about efficiency of code at that moment.

Comment: @ja213214215 . . . That is how you find connected components.  You need to traverse the subgraphs.

Comment: Ok, big thanks to you. Appreciate it a lot! I will try to modify my tables  in some way then. Thanks again GordonLinoff and @SeanLange